# Can I open local file url with Safari by Application::openURL method in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, web

I need to launch a page in my ios app, but want it to be launched outside of my app, because this page will redirect user to a bank page to pay.

I do not have the direct Bank URL on hand, all depends on the redirection action.

I 'd like to open it with Safari outside of my app, in that case, the bank url address will be showed, app user will feel secure.

Embed a bank page in a UIWebview looks not good.

is that possible, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"https://www.mybank.com/?shop=pipco&customer=rdnzl&product=muffin"]];
```

Comment: I do not have the url, only a html form, I need submit the form to the desination bank url

Comment: If the GET method is used, you could extract the field names from the form and fill in the values. For POST this won't work.